# Как вытащить url из объекта PHP

Tags: php

$per->term_thumbnail; - вот так получил это:

```
{"filename":"sport.jpg",
    "uploadedTo":0,
    "subtype":"jpeg",
    "id":84,
    "title":"sport",
    "url":"http://mysite.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/sport.jpg"},
```

Как теперь можно получить только url

Пробовал:

```
$per->term_thumbnail->url;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = '{"filename":"sport.jpg",
    "uploadedTo":0,
    "subtype":"jpeg",
    "id":84,
    "title":"sport",
    "url":"http://mysite.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/sport.jpg"}';

echo json_decode($string)->url;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: "@МихаилВолков, всегда пожалуйста :)